# Facebook Graph API for online friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, I am using the Facebook's FQL API to query the user's all friends online_presence but as Facebook have declared that these FQLs will not be supported after Aug, 2016. So I need some version graph api V2.2 or above.

Also, do let me know if there is any privileged api for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is support in the API nor in the upcoming roadmap for online friends. The comment from the Facebook employee above is true, this is not possible, there are no workarounds and no privileged API.